# CAT FILE with sort lines by DATE column

Tags: shell, sort

I have a text file that contains the log info about the webserver.

DATE Format: Day-Month-Year

Sample content:

```
/tmp/archive/9-10-2020/error_04.log.gz
/tmp/archive/9-10-2020/error_05.log.gz
/tmp/archive/9-7-2020/access_01.log.gz
/tmp/archive/9-7-2020/access_02.log.gz
/tmp/archive/9-7-2020/access_03.log.gz
/tmp/archive/9-7-2020/error_03.log.gz
/tmp/archive/9-7-2020/error_04.log.gz
/tmp/archive/9-7-2020/error_05.log.gz
/tmp/archive/9-8-2020/error_01.log.gz
/tmp/archive/9-8-2020/error_02.log.gz
/tmp/archive/9-8-2020/error_03.log.gz
/tmp/archive/9-8-2020/error_04.log.gz
/tmp/archive/9-8-2020/error_05.log.gz
/tmp/archive/9-9-2020/access_01.log.gz
/tmp/archive/9-9-2020/access_02.log.gz
/tmp/archive/9-9-2020/access_03.log.gz
```

I want to list this content based on the date order(the 3rd column). I tried sort command, its not giving the sort by date.

Expected output:

```
/tmp/archive/9-7-2020/access_01.log.gz
/tmp/archive/9-7-2020/access_02.log.gz
/tmp/archive/9-7-2020/access_03.log.gz
/tmp/archive/9-7-2020/error_03.log.gz
/tmp/archive/9-7-2020/error_04.log.gz
/tmp/archive/9-7-2020/error_05.log.gz
/tmp/archive/9-8-2020/error_01.log.gz
/tmp/archive/9-8-2020/error_02.log.gz
/tmp/archive/9-8-2020/error_03.log.gz
/tmp/archive/9-8-2020/error_04.log.gz
/tmp/archive/9-8-2020/error_05.log.gz
/tmp/archive/9-9-2020/access_01.log.gz
/tmp/archive/9-9-2020/access_02.log.gz
/tmp/archive/9-9-2020/access_03.log.gz
/tmp/archive/9-10-2020/error_04.log.gz
/tmp/archive/9-10-2020/error_05.log.gz
```

Update:

```
Sort syntax:
sort -k4.7,4.11 -k4,5

/tmp/backup/7-12-2020/access_04.log
/tmp/backup/7-12-2020/error_02.log
/tmp/backup/7-12-2020/error_03.log
/tmp/backup/7-12-2020/error_04.log
/tmp/backup/7-12-2020/error_05.log
/tmp/backup/8-11-2020/access_01.log
/tmp/backup/8-11-2020/access_02.log
/tmp/backup/8-12-2020/error_01.log
/tmp/backup/8-12-2020/error_02.log
/tmp/backup/8-12-2020/error_03.log
/tmp/backup/8-12-2020/error_04.log
/tmp/backup/8-12-2020/error_05.log
/tmp/backup/9-11-2020/access_01.log
/tmp/backup/9-11-2020/access_02.log
/tmp/backup/9-11-2020/access_03.log
/tmp/backup/9-11-2020/access_04.log
```

Comment: If you wrote your log files with dates in the format `yyyy-mm-dd` you wouldn't have this sorting problem

Comment: I agree with the date format, but i have to process the existing files.

Comment: "_3rd column_" presumably means "_4th `/`-separated field_"?

Comment: yes, you are right

Comment: So is there a requirement also to maintain the implied ordering of the filenames `access_01.log.gz`, `access_02.log.gz`, etc. for a given date?

Comment: Yes, correct. But its not mandatory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a specific pattern such as this you can split the pathname into its `/` and `-` separated components, putting them at the beginning of the line,

```
awk '{
    split($0, f, "[/-]");
    printf "%04d-%02d-%02d\t%s\t%s\n", f[6], f[5], f[4], f[7], $0
}'
```

then sort the date (`yyyy-mm-dd`) and filename (e.g. `access_NN.log.gz`) accordingly

```
sort
```

and finally strip off the sorting components

```
cut -f3-
```

Assuming the sample data is in the file `/tmp/logs` you can put it together like this

```
awk '{ split($0, f, "[/-]"); printf "%04d-%02d-%02d\t%s\t%s\n", f[6], f[5], f[4], f[7], $0 }' /tmp/logs |
    sort |
    cut -f3-

/tmp/archive/9-7-2020/access_01.log.gz
/tmp/archive/9-7-2020/access_02.log.gz
/tmp/archive/9-7-2020/access_03.log.gz
/tmp/archive/9-7-2020/error_03.log.gz
/tmp/archive/9-7-2020/error_04.log.gz
/tmp/archive/9-7-2020/error_05.log.gz
/tmp/archive/9-8-2020/error_01.log.gz
/tmp/archive/9-8-2020/error_02.log.gz
/tmp/archive/9-8-2020/error_03.log.gz
/tmp/archive/9-8-2020/error_04.log.gz
/tmp/archive/9-8-2020/error_05.log.gz
/tmp/archive/9-9-2020/access_01.log.gz
/tmp/archive/9-9-2020/access_02.log.gz
/tmp/archive/9-9-2020/access_03.log.gz
/tmp/archive/9-10-2020/error_04.log.gz
/tmp/archive/9-10-2020/error_05.log.gz
```

Comment: Just for my understanding, `split($0, f, "[/-]")` how this convert the `dd-mm-yyyy` to `yyyy-mm-dd` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here, assuming all lines always start with `/tmp/archive/` or anything the  same length, you could do:

```
sort -t- -k3,3.4n -k1.14,1n -k2,2n -k3.5
```

Which here you can simplify it to:

```
sort -t- -k3n -k1.14n -k2n -k3.5
```

as `-` is not going to be a thousand separator in any locale (since it's also the character for the negative sign), so with the `n` flag, a key specification of `-k1.14n` (which would select `7-12-2020/access_04.log` on the first line for instance) or `-k1.14,1n` (which would select only `7`) would both yield the `7` *number*.

Comment: Its sorting only based on day (like `1-1-2020,1-2-2020,2-1-2020`)